# UICollection View - 3 Questions: Locking a Cell? Sharing Data? ViewDidLoad Background Color

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on my finishing touches for a school project, hoping I could ask for a helping hand. 3 questions. The app is a color generating app. Where every time the user swipes 5 new colors are generated.

1. I want to lock one cell in place, but still be able to generate new colors for the other cells.
2. Currently if you click on a cell an alert will appear and you can share the hex code. I want to make a button that will share all 5 hex codes
3. When the app first opens 5 random colors are generated how do I make it where I can set the first 5 colors to my decision? After the user swipes then they can generate new colors.

   ```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

   @IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!

   var colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor]()
   var hexcode: [String] = [String]()
   var indexPath = NSIndexPath()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handSwipeReset:"))
       let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handSwipeReset:"))

       leftSwipe.direction = .Left
       rightSwipe.direction = .Right

       view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
       view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)        

       self.generateColors(amount: 5)
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
       if self.colors.count > 0 {
           return self.colors.count
       } else {
           return 0
       }
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("colorCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
       as! ColorCell

       cell.backgroundColor = self.colors[indexPath.row]
       cell.hexCode.text = hexcode[indexPath.row]

       return cell
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height / 5.71)
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       let message = self.hexcode[indexPath.row]
       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hexcode", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: shareButton))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
       self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   func shareButton(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
       print("Share")
   }

   func randomNumber () -> CGFloat {
       return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX))
   }

   func generateColors(amount amount: Int) {
       for _ in 0..<amount {
           self.makeColor()
       }

       self.collectionView.reloadData()

   }

   func handSwipeReset(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
       if (sender.direction == .Left || sender.direction == .Right) {
           self.hexcode.removeAll()
           self.colors.removeAll()
           self.generateColors(amount: 5)
           self.collectionView.reloadData()
       }
   }

   func makeColor () {
       let red = randomNumber ()
       let green = randomNumber ()
       let blue = randomNumber ()
       let backgroundColor = UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
       self.hexcode.append(hexy(color: backgroundColor))
       self.colors.append(backgroundColor)
   }

   func hexy(color color: UIColor) -> String {
       let components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor)
       var hex = ""
       for i in 0...2 {
           let int = Int(components[i] * 255)
           let hexcode = String(int, radix: 16)
           if hexcode.characters.count < 2 {
               hex = hex + "0\(hexcode)"
           } else {
               hex = hex + hexcode
           }
       }

       return "#\(hex)"
   }
   ```

   }